# empty screen while running my random numbers program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'd like to write a basic program which is generating random numbers that are different from each other but when I run the program I always see a empty screen. I think there is a logical error where I check the numbers that they're not similar with each others and then stuck in "for" loop. Could you examine my code? Thanks..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace denemeTahtasi2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[7];

            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
            c:
                numbers[i] = random.Next(1, 50);
                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                    {
                        goto c;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in numbers)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

note: Yes, I know I can do it using .contains method but I want to figure it out whats wrong with this program.

Comment: You should try not to use a goto statement. It will become less readable if it grows.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger to see what path it takes through the code?  Also, you've tagged this question with [tag:runtime-error], but if I understand the question there is no error or any output at all.

Comment: To “figure it out whats wrong” you need to [learn how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Pay particularly close attention to `if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]` (you're going into an infinte loop when you check the same variable against itself).

Comment: A trick would be using `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)` because if you compare it behind `i`, there will probably be zero's

Comment: As you don't seed the randomiser with anything it should return the same series every time. Alas you can step through it and see where it get stuck. If I am wrong and it does create a new series every time, try seeding it with a known value, e.g. 1, and see if it get stuck. If it does, you can debug it line by line.

Comment: @LosManos The default seed for `Random` is based on the current time, so it's unlikely it'd be the same seed and, therefore, sequence on successive runs.  To get the same seed you'd have to, as you've said, explicitly pass a constant seed to the constructor.

Comment: Your use of `goto` is a very bad choice. Frankly, the language shouldn't have `goto` in the first place, and there's no good reason to use it here. It just makes the code harder to understand. Worse though is that you don't seem to have used a debugger to watch what the code does, so you can understand the problem. Your question lacks evidence of research, and the problem is caused by a simple mistake in your loop termination. The answer to the question is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: thank you for showing my mistakes, I will research how to fix my problem without using goto statement and how to use debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an endless loop. Both `i` and `j` start out at `0`, so when you do `if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])`, it will always return `true` because you're looking at the same index. Then you hit the `goto` statement and do it all over again.

To fix this, add an `if` condition to skip the comparison if `i` and `j` are the same index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    c:
    numbers[i] = random.Next(1, 50);
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
    {
        // If i and j are the same index, skip the comparison
        if (i == j) continue;

        if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
        {
            goto c;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, since we don't need to look at any numbers *after* index `i`, we can improve the code slightly by limiting `j` to numbers that are less than `i`. In this way, we no longer need the comparison, since `j` will always be less than `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    c:
    numbers[i] = random.Next(1, 50);

    // Only compare indexes that are before this one
    // (since we haven't set any after this one yet)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
        {
            goto c;
        }
    }
}
```